# Button is not touchable

Tags: ios, button, view, action, frame

I've set up views and buttons programatically, and i'm adding/removing views a lot. What i'm doing is also adding buttons on certain views, and i'm having trouble with a very specific one.

**The structure :**

I have a main view, on top of which i added another view (same size, which is the whole size of the tablet). This view contains buttons, images, etc. This is all working fine there.
One of these buttons is a "menu" which makes a simple menu appear so you can navigate to other views. This menu is another view (a third one) that adds itself on top of everything. Works fine here too.

Important note : that menu is very small compared to the whole frame, but the menu view still takes the whole space, its just 70% transparent.

**The problem :**

What is not working, is my way to remove that menu when, for example, i decide to click in the transparent space that is around my visible menu, it just closes it.

To do that, i decided to add a transparent background button (that takes the whole frame and is just behind my visible menu, but still in my menu view frame).

So basically : i click on a button and it closes views and just does stuff. Here is the code i'm using :
(...)

```
UIButton *backgroundCloser = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:_menuViewController.view.frame];
    [backgroundCloser addTarget:self action:@selector(closeMenuView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backgroundCloser.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    backgroundCloser.alpha = 0.2;

    [self.view addSubview:backgroundCloser];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:backgroundCloser];
    [self.view addSubview:_menuViewController.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_menuViewController.view];

- (void)closeMenuView{ 
    stuff }
```

Right now my button is slightly orange and transparent so i'm sure its there. And i can see it. But my " closemenuview " NEVER gets called on tap. or at all.

I've tried putting it as IBAction, but in vain.

Any clue of what's happening to my baby?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding buttons on various view try writing

```
YOUR_View.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and setUp Button as below

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

It's always the same, i look for everything for about an hour, and as soon as i post on stack, i just find the answer by myself.

I was simply adding it to the wrong view (`self.view`) instead of `_menuviewcontroller.view`.

Comment: I answered the same.. I asked where you have added the button. Anyways good job.